# Protractor: command not found when trying to run in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, protractor

Running my Protractor test from Jenkins by executing shell script `protractor conf.js` , but getting error:

```
+ export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
+ PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
+ protractor conf.js
[19:45:23] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[19:45:23] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[19:45:23] E/direct - Error code: 135
[19:45:23] E/direct - Error message: Could not find update-config.json. Run 'webdriver-manager update' to download binaries.
[19:45:23] E/direct - Error: Could not find update-config.json. Run 'webdriver-manager update' to download binaries.
    at Direct.getNewDriver (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/direct.js:63:31)
    at Runner.createBrowser (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:195:43)
    at q.then.then (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:339:29)
    at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:556:49
    at runSingle (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
    at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
[19:45:23] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 135
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 1):

The error told you `can't find protractor in PATH environment`. You used global protractor, thus you need to install a global protractor and expose it's install location to `PATH` environment.

But I recommend you use local protractor which installed by `npm install` and will be installed into /node_modules. With using local protractor, you should change your shell to `node_modules/bin/protractor conf.js`

```
export PATH=`npm config get prefix`/bin:$PATH
webdriver-manager update <if your network behind proxy, please add option: --proxy=your_proxy_address>
protractor conf.js
```

Comment: I have installed it globally, but how do I expose it to PATH environment?

Comment: use `export` to change the `PATH` environment before execute protractor cmd

Comment: You need to download webdriver at first by execute `webdriver-manager update`